# Snowflake COPY INTO Export Producing Unreadable File

Tags: export-to-csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Testing export functionality in Snowflake and having a hard time getting a readable file back.

Using the below command on:

```
COPY INTO 'azure://my_account.blob.core.windows.net/test-folder/test_file_8.csv'
FROM (SELECT * FROM DEMO_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES)
credentials = (azure_sas_token='my_sas_token')
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV RECORD_DELIMITER = ',')
HEADER = TRUE
SINGLE = TRUE
```

I'm getting the following back:
[See Exported Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTnaU.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try COMPRESSION=NONE in your copy options? CSV files are automatically compressed using gzip. It should append .gz on the file extension, but it may not have if you specified the file name entirely.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped. Noticing that I'm getting random \ characters appended to data. How do we remove these?

Comment: The backslash is the default escape character for the CSV file format type. You can change that using the ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD parameter. Before suppressing it, which can lead to invalid CSV files, you may want to add FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' to wrap them in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

From [COPY INTO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html) docs:

> If SINGLE = TRUE, then COPY ignores the FILE_EXTENSION file format option and outputs a file simply named data. To specify a file extension, provide a filename and extension in the internal or external location path
>
> COPY INTO @mystage/data.csv ...

and:

> COMPRESSION = AUTO | GZIP | BZ2 | BROTLI | ZSTD | DEFLATE | RAW_DEFLATE | NONE
>
> String (constant) that specifies to compresses the unloaded data files using the specified compression algorithm.
>
> Supported Values
> AUTO
> **Unloaded files are automatically compressed using the default, which is gzip.**
>
> ```
> **Default: AUTO**
> ```

Either do not compress file(compression method NONE) or provide a proper file name with `gz` extension:
`COPY INTO 'azure://my_account.blob.core.windows.net/test-folder/test_file_8.csv.gz'`